# HttpContext.Current seems to be null on ServiceStack content page

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.31, hosted on IIS. When executing a *content* razor page, the `HttpContext.Current` seems to be null. 
The use of the `AntiForgery` helper methods needs this property to be defined.

I was assuming that the ServiceStack hosting layer ensured the propagation of this static property, when hosting over IIS.

Is this assumption wrong or is this behavior an error?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest version of ServiceStack?

Comment: Updated to 4.0.38 and the problem seems to be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to 4.0.38 seems to have fixed this problem. I was using the https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts demo app, which still used the 4.0.31 version